# How to scroll the followers modal window in instagram?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I am writing a parser for instagram profile subscribers using selenium in python. I open a modal window with subscribers and then I start asking questions, how do I scroll through this modal window to load all subscribers?

I have found solutions, but I can't get this modal window by xpath. For some reason it doesn't want to find this item.

Help me, please!